# Mushrooms pushing up

Tags: lawn

My buddy has 6 inch smaller and bigger, mushrooms growing under his lawn. All over his lawn. He wants to know why? Lol. And how to get rid of them. They are leaving huge and deep holes.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a picture or two, so that we can see what you mean with “under” the lawn and what kind of holes?

Comment: Does your buddy live in a house that was recently constructed - say, within the last 3-5 years?